# Is this proof that the irrational number set is a Baire space correct?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, the-baire-space

I know there's proof that the irrational number set is a Baire space, but when I tried to prove this, I used a different way. However, I feel my proof is not right.

Let $I= \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$， I want to prove it is a Baire space. I tried to show that if $\left\{ B_{n} \right\}$ is a family of closed set in $I$ with empty interior, then $$\begin{align*}
\bigcup\limits_{n} B_{n}
\end{align*}$$ still has empty interior in $I$

Consider any closed set in $I$, it should be in the form $I \cap F$ where $F$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Then it has the empty interior. That is,  $I \cap F$ does not contain any open set in $\mathbb{R}$. This is since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ intersects with $\mathbb{Q}$ nontrivially, so if $I \cap F$ does contain an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, it must contain some rational numbers. This is a contradiction.

Consider let $B_{n}= I \cap F_{n}$ where $F_{n}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ , then I think $$\begin{align*}
\bigcup\limits B_{n} \subset I
\end{align*}$$it shouldn't contain any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ . This is still since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, so if the union contains any open set of $\mathbb{R}$, then it must contain some rational numbers which contradict with $\bigcup\limits B_{n} \subset I$.

I doubt the correctness of my proof. Is this the right proof? If this is wrong, where it goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: For $I$ to be Baire, you need to show that countable unions of nowhere dense sets closed in $I$ is nowhere dense in $I$, not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Ningxin In Munkres Topology, It defines that $A \subset X$ and $A$ has empty interior means $A$ doesn't contain any open set in $X$ . Then the Baire space is defined that any countable closed set family $\left\{ B_{n} \right\}$ in $X$ where each $B_{n}$ has empty interior satisfies that $\bigcup\limits_{n} B_{n}$ still has empty interior. I want to prove $I$ is a Baire space, so I just found a general countable closed set family with each element that has empty interior and tried to show the union doesn't contain any open set in $\mathbb{R}$. At least I think my idea is right...

Comment: You have to show that the union doesn't contain any open subset of $I$, not $\mathbb{R}$.